# LESSCSS check if closest parent has class

Tags: css, less

I use:

```
.first{
    .second{
        .third{
            .between_second_and_third & {
                /* some rules */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the end I have:

```
.between_second_and_third .first .second .third {/* some rules */}
```

But I want:

```
.first .second .between_second_and_third .third {/* some rules */}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `&` marker refers to the current parent selector (as mentioned [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature))

That's why you've got this final statement cause you defined something like that:

```
.first{
    .second{
        .third{
            .between_second_and_third .first .second .third {
                /* some rules */
            }
        }
  }
```

You just have to nest your `between_second_and_third` class between... `.second` and `.third` class declarations like this:

```
.first{
    /* first rules */
    .second{
       /* rules for second */
       .between_second_and_third {
          /* rules between */
          .third{
           /* some other rules */            
        }
    }
}
```

This declaration render this lines of CSS code:

```
.first { /* first rules */ }
.first .second { /* rules for second */ }
.first .second .between_second_and_third {/* rules between */}
.first .second .between_second_and_third .third {/* some other rules */}
```

Comment: Thus, it is impossible. Ok.